# Subsetting a column where all values are the same character value in r

Tags: r, subset

I am trying to identify data frame columns where the columns have a single character value `tree`.

Here is an example dataset.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 var.1 = c(5,6,7,"tree",4),
                 var.2 = c("tree","tree","tree","tree","tree"),
                 var.3 = c(4,5,8,9,1))

> df
  id var.1 var.2 var.3
1  1     5  tree     4
2  2     6  tree     5
3  3     7  tree     8
4  4  tree  tree     9
5  5     4  tree     1
```

I would flag the `Var.2` variable since it has all `"tree` values in it.

> flagged
> [1] "var.2"

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each column, check if all elements equal the first element.

```r
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 var.1 = c(5,6,7,"tree",4),
                 var.2 = c("tree","tree","tree","tree","tree"),
                 var.3 = c(4,5,8,9,1))


names(df)[sapply(df, function(x) all(x == x[1]))]
#> [1] "var.2"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your solution. This worked great. I used something similar `which(sapply(bm.data, function(x) length(unique(x))) == 1) # ` but this gave me the column number instead of column name.

Answer (score 3):

Using dplyr, you could do

```
library(dplyr)

flagged <- df %>%
  select(where(~n_distinct(.x) == 1 && unique(.x) == "tree")) %>%
  names()
```

where you select all columns that only have one distinct value which equals "tree", and then extract the column names.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Which library should I use for the `where` function?

Comment: Sorry, that's in dplyr too - I'll add it to my example.